# Django-Rest-Framework JWT Unit Test Saying "No Authentication Provided"

Tags: python, unit-testing, django-rest-framework, jwt

When I attempt to do a unit a test I get the error:

> "detail":"Authentication credentials were not provided."

However, I am using django-rest-framework-jwt, which wants the web token placed at the header as "Authorization: JWT ".  I did a wireshark on a working, accepted packet from my website and it had the Authorization: JWT header.  As does my current request which is rejected.  I can't figure out why it's failing.

Adding force_authenticate allows it to run, but I'd like to test my permissions.

Here is the reference from the Documentation:

> Now in order to access protected api urls you must include the
>   Authorization: JWT  header.

[django-rest-framework-jwt documentation](https://github.com/GetBlimp/django-rest-framework-jwt/blob/master/docs/index.md)

Here is the request from PyCharm:

```
{'REQUEST_METHOD': 'PATCH', 
'CONTENT_TYPE': 'application/json; charset=None', 
'CONTENT_LENGTH': 74, 
'PATH_INFO': '/api/v1/members/5', 
'QUERY_STRING': '', 
'Authorization': 'JWT eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ1c2VybmFtZSI6InVzZXIiLCJlbWFpbCI6ImVtYWlsQGdtYWlsLmNvbSIsInVzZXJfaWQiOjUsImV4cCI6MTQzNzUzOTE4MH0.cGcXw9srOYgbeICdbMw8Ey_ya9eBRD-ptRsGwd2jzlk', 
'wsgi.input': <django.test.client.FakePayload object at 0x106689748>
}
```

Here is the code:

```
class ModifyTest(APITestCase):
    """ Test modifying users, to include member_profile
    """
    username = 'user'
    password = 'passwd'
    token = 0
    user_id = 0

    def setUp(self):
        data = {'username': self.username,
                'password': self.password,
                'email': 'email@gmail.com'}
        url = reverse('members:auth-user-create')
        response = self.client.post(url, data, format='json')
        self.user_id = response.data['id']

        data = {'username': self.username,
                'password': self.password}
        url = reverse('token_auth')
        response = self.client.post(url, data, format='json')
        self.token = response.data['token']

    def test_auth_user_info(self):
        data = {'id': str(self.user_id),
                'password': self.password,
                'email': 'email@gmail.com',
                'username': self.username,
                }
        url = reverse('members:auth-user-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.user_id})
        response = self.client.patch(url, data, Authorization='JWT ' + self.token, format='son')
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
```

Update:
When stepping through the authentication I realized that my view is not using the correct authentication classes.  Below is my settings though...

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        #'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
        #'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
        'rest_framework_jwt.authentication.JSONWebTokenAuthentication',
    ),
}
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_FILTER_BACKENDS': ('rest_framework.filters.DjangoFilterBackend',)
}
```

And my view:

```
class AuthUserDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    permission_classes = (IsOwnerOrAdmin,)
    queryset = get_user_model().objects.all()
    serializer_class = AuthUserModelSerializer
```

However, my permission classes in my debugger when the view is called are:

```
<class 'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication'>, 
<class 'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication'>
```

So adding this line to my view fixes it:

```
authentication_classes = (JSONWebTokenAuthentication,)
```

But that shouldn't be needed with the default classes selected... any ideas why it isn't using the defaults?

Comment: What happens when you execute `curl -H "Authorization: JWT <your_token>" http://localhost:8000/api/v1/members/5/`?

Comment: Yah... so below is the reason I wasted way too much time on this problem... hopefully no one else makes that mistake.  It took me so long to notice because it was only a factor on modify and I was wiresharking a view that allowed any authentication... not smart, should have done the curl and saved myself hours.  Thanks

Comment: Yes i'm facing same error i added autentication_classes =[JSONWebTokenAuthentication]... Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out... I didn't recognize I had two sections of REST_FRAMEWORK so obviously the second was overwriting the first erasing my defaults... new settings file:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework_jwt.authentication.JSONWebTokenAuthentication',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_FILTER_BACKENDS': ('rest_framework.filters.DjangoFilterBackend',)
}
```